# Calculate probability vector from sample data

Tags: probability, python, spatial

I'd like to compare two distributions using Jensen-Shannon Divergence metric. To do this, I need two **probability vectors** to plug into `distance.jensenshannon(p, q)`. From the [scipy.spatial documentation](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.jensenshannon.html).

> scipy.spatial.distance.jensenshannon(p, q, base=None)[source]
>
> Parameters:
>
> p(N,) array_like left **probability vector**
>
> q(N,) array_like right **probability vector**

**Question**

How can I calculate probability vectors from sample data?

**Example:**

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

x1 = np.random.normal(size=100)
x2 = np.random.normal(size=100)

p = 

q = 

jsd_metric = distance.jensenshannon(p, q)
```

Can I accomplish this using `scipy.stats.norm.pdf()`?

```
p = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x1)
q = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x2)
```

Comment: There are at least four distributions in evidence: the Normal distributions used to generate data and the empirical distributions of the data.  Exactly which distributions do you wish to compare?

Comment: I want to compare `x1` and `x2`. So I want to compare the empirical distribution of `x1` and `x2`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know this test but if I base my code on that formula:

[image]

where M = (P+Q)/2 and D(Q|M) the KLD between Q and M (same for D(P|M) so on python I do this:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats

x1 = np.random.normal(size=100)
x2 = np.random.normal(size=100)

p = scipy.stats.norm.cdf(x1)
q = scipy.stats.norm.cdf(x2)

m = (p + q) / 2

divergence = (scipy.stats.entropy(p,m) + scipy.stats.entropy(q,m)) / 2

distance = np.sqrt(divergence)
```

Comment: Thanks! Why `scipy.stats.norm.cdf()`? Why not `.pdf()`

Comment: I don't think it impacts the results that much, I read "probability distribution" so I used CDF instinctively but a PDF is also a description of a probability distribution.

I'm not familiar with this test but since you only need "probability vector", I think either PDF or CDF are good enough.